# SSAS Visual Studio 2019 - Cambiar de cultura en un Modelo Tabular

Tags: visual-studio, ssas

Estoy trabajando con un modelos tabular en visual studio 2019.
Cuando importe el proyecto, ya venia con una cultura: en-US.
Lo necesito cambiar a español, alguien me puede decir como puedo cambiarlo ?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.